# Async Await / Promise / API Google Tradutor Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Comecei a utilizar a API do Google Tradutor (Google Cloud Translate API) hoje e não estou conseguindo aplicar o `async`/`await` na função `translate`. Segue o código:

```
const api = require("../keys/google-translate.json").API_KEY
const googleTranslate = require("google-translate")(api);

googleTranslate.translate(text, "pt-BR", function (err, translation) {
    console.log(translation.translatedText)
});
```

Teria alguma maneira de fazer esta função retornar uma `Promise` para que eu consiga utilizar o `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma `Promise` explicitamente. Você já pesquisou sobre o funcionamento básico de uma promessa?

Basicamente, toda `Promise` funciona assim:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // Quando o trabalho assíncrono estiver feito,
  // basta chamar o `resolve`, passando um valor qualquer.
  resolve(__QUALQUER_VALOR__);

  // Em um eventual erro, rejeitamos a promessa:
  reject(new Error('Whoops!'));
});
```

Para saber mais, leia [este excelente artigo do Jake Archibald](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-BR) e a [documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Então, no seu caso, basta usar o que vimos acima:

```js
const api = require("../keys/google-translate.json").API_KEY
const googleTranslate = require("google-translate")(api);

function translateText(text) {
  // Note que a função retorna uma `Promise`. Poderemos, então, usar `async`/`await`.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    googleTranslate.translate(text, 'pt-BR', function (err, translation) {
      if (err) {
        // No caso de erro, a promessa será rejeitada.
        reject(err);
      } else {
        // No sucesso, a promessa será resolvida.
        resolve(translation);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Em node tem o [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) que faz a conversão de uma função callback para promise. Ele faz automaticamente o processo descrito pelo Luiz Felipe, mas atenção promisify converte apenas callbacks como ultimo parâmetro, e callbacks que tenham de erro como primeiro parâmetro.

```
const api = require("../keys/google-translate.json").API_KEY
const googleTranslate = require("google-translate")(api);
const util = require('util')

util.promisify(googleTranslate.translate)(text, "pt-BR");
```

Comment: Ótima ideia. Nem tinha pensado em usar o `promisify`... Mas realmente, é válido!! O único problema é se os _callbacks_ da função forem fora do padrão... +1 :)